# How to delete that rows, when i get text from URL?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, nsdata, nsurl

i try to get some text from an URL and put it out in a `UITextView`.
Thats my code in the `ViewController`:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http:/...";
NSError  *error     = nil;
NSData   *dataURL   = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if (error)
    NSLog(@"%s: dataWithContentsOfURL error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
else
{
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%s: result = %@", __FUNCTION__, result);

    // if you were updating a label with an `IBOutlet` called `resultLabel`, you'd do something like:

    self.mytextview.text = result;
}
```

Now the simulator shows that text in my view:
[image]

Sorry, the text is german :)

Now how can I hide or delete that html, head, body etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It displays like this because you are downloading the content of that PHP file which is in HTML format.

You can create a method to find & delete each HTML tag between "<" and ">"

```
- (NSString*)stringByRemovingHTMLtags:(NSString*)string {
  NSRange range;
  while ((range = [string rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    string = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
  return string;
}
```

Then set your text in the UITextView like this:

```
 self.mytextview.text = [self stringByRemovingHTMLtags:result];
```

---

**EDIT**: In order to get the content of the `<p>` tag use this method:

```
- (NSString*)getPtagContentFromString:(NSString*)htmlString {
    NSRange startRange = [htmlString rangeOfString:@"<p>"];
    if (startRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSRange targetRange;
        targetRange.location = startRange.location + startRange.length;
        targetRange.length = [htmlString length] - targetRange.location;
        NSRange endRange = [htmlString rangeOfString:@"</p>" options:0 range:targetRange];
        if (endRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            targetRange.length = endRange.location - targetRange.location;
            return [htmlString substringWithRange:targetRange];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Then set your text in the UITextView like this:

```
 self.mytextview.text = [self getPtagContentFromString:result];
```

Comment: Hey Sebyddd, thanks. The solution above works fine. I will try yours too.

Comment: Sure, you can use @fic's solution if you're using UIWebView, but i don't see any reason why you would do that if you're downloading the content of a webpage.

Comment: I tried and I like your solution but it shows the title also "PHP-Test".I only want the text between the "p"s. How can I handle that?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and load your html text like this:

```
[_webView loadHTMLString:result baseURL:nil];
```